# Set initial value for api slice rtk query

Tags: redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I am using the RTK query
In the UserApiSlice I have `/me` endpoint which returns the user name, email, etc.
I decided to return the cart in the same endpoint so I don't have to use another fetch to get the cart ( I also have Cart Api slice)
But I am wondering how to set the cart that I am getting from the /me API slice to the cart API slice
( I am doing this so I can know whether the user has the product in the cart or not)

In summary
How to set an initial value(that you get from another APiSlice) for Api Slice of RTK query

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703677/update-other-slice-after-request